# airflow max_active_run is not increasing

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

my dag code

```
dag = DAG(
    "ETL_s21_{}_impression_product_test".format("every_minute"),
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="* * * * *",
    max_active_runs=10,
    concurrency=5
)


def export_impression_log(table, item):
    export_impression_log_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"{table}_{item}_export_impression_log",
            python_callable=S3.export_impression_log_from_ad_s3,
            op_kwargs={
                "execution_date": '{{execution_date.in_timezone("Asia/Seoul").strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")}}',
                'table': table,
                'item': item
            },
            dag=dag,
            queue='s21',
            task_concurrency=5,
            provide_context=False
        )

    return export_impression_log_task


def add_partition(table, item):
    add_partition_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f"{table}_{item}_add_partition",
        python_callable=Athena.add_partition,
        op_kwargs={
            "glue_table_name": 'amplitude_impression_test',
            "execution_date": '{{execution_date.in_timezone("UTC").strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")}}'
        },
        dag=dag,
        queue='s21',
        task_concurrency=5,
        provide_context=False
    )
```

airflow.cfg

```
dag_concurrency = 16
worker_concurrency = 16
parallelism = 32
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
```

dag runs every minutes and start from past. then, i expected it start from start_date and being created max 5 dag at once and 5 dag is keep going.

but max active run dag instances are 2 and it doesn't increase.

[image]

[image]

i think already tested about option for concurrency / parallelism. but coudn't solve this problem.

what should i check?

Comment: which executor are you using?

Comment: @SaverioGuzzo i'm using CeleryExecutor

Comment: do you have the same problem using LocalExecutor?

Comment: i've never tried. should i ?